# Why does my PyCharm give a warning regarding this scrapy's function signature?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wiki_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:愤怒的小鸟系列电子游戏',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'wiki-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

My code above is a copy of this tutorial:

```
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html
```

But why does my Pycharm give a warning regarding the parse function's signature?

```
Signature of method 'WikiSpider.parse()' does not match signature of base method in class 'Spider'
```

Is this a false alarm?

Answer (score 2):

Because the parse method inside of class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider) also has another parameter **kwargs. I don't think this causes any errors while running the program, but adding **kwargs does remove the warning.